# Checkpoint Secure Client: "Connectivity with VPN services is lost" on Mac OS 10.8

Tags: macos, startup, vpn, launchd

When I install the secure client from Checkpoint ([from here](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=15261)) on my Mac OS X 10.8, it works.

However, as soon as I restart the Laptop for 1-2 times, it won't work anymore displaying the error:

> Connectivity with VPN services is lost

whenever clicking an option from the menu bar icon or trying to connect.

Every 10 seconds, this is written to system.log:

```
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.checkpoint.epc.service[1211]): Exited with code: 1
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.checkpoint.epc.service): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

Are there any solutions or possible reasons for this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions, not general computer problems.

Answer (score 6):

Since the question wasn't answered inline by the previous answers, I'll post it here.

I'm not sure of the underlying cause, but this happens when one of the Checkpoint config files gets truncated. Fix it by cd'ing to `/Library/Application Support/Checkpoint/Endpoint Connect` then copy from the backup file with: `sudo cp Trac.config.bak Trac.config`.  Note that this is in `/Library` **not* `~/Library`. It's a global setting not per user.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after trying to disable loading the Endpoint client at startup. It was easier to simply download the latest package from here https://www.checkpoint.com/products/remote-access-vpn, then uninstall and install the client again. Now it works as before.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Windows, but maybe interesting.
It seems like Valorant Players Antichecheat Vanguard blocks the VPN:

try to deinstall Vanguard reboot and try again.

https://community.checkpoint.com/t5/Endpoint/Connectivity-with-the-Check-Point-Endpoint-Security-service-is/m-p/124679/highlight/true#

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35523659)

Comment: Oh, I initially believed my response was precisely on point. The root cause of the problem appears to be related to Valorant's anti-cheat system. To resolve this issue, it seems that the most effective method is to uninstall it and then reboot the system. What additional details or suggestions would you recommend adding to my response to make it more comprehensive?

Comment: It seemed there are some additional details in the link that should be added to the post. However, I have checked it precisely and I see it is fine as it is. Don't mind my mistake during the review of your question.